# Show/hide text based on selected radio button js

Tags: javascript, html

I'm still learning javascript and I have got into a dead end with this.

So, this is what I'm trying to achieve:
I have 3 options - **Typography, with spiral and with unryu paper.**

```
 <fieldset>
        <legend id="type">Book type:</legend>
        <input type="radio" name="books" id="book1" value="book1" onchange="updateTotal()">1.Tipography
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="books" id="book2" value="book2" onchange="updateTotal()">2.With spiral
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="books" id="book3" value="book3" onchange="updateTotal()">3.With unryu paper
        <br>
    </fieldset>
```

When select **Typography** - I want to show this option:

```
        <fieldset>
        <legend id="tipcolor">1.Choose tipography book color:</legend>
        <input type="radio" name="color" id="color1" value="color1" onchange="updateTotal()">green
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="color" id="color2" value="color2" onchange="updateTotal()">orange
        <br>
        </fieldset>
```

And hide all others, except **Shipping** (that must be visible all the time).

The same for other option - when selected **With spiral** - show this option:

```
        <fieldset>
        <label id="color" class="hidden">2.Chooes spiral book color:</label>
        <input type="radio" name="color" id="color3" value="color3" onchange="updateTotal()">green
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="color" id="color4" value="color4" onchange="updateTotal()">blue
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="color" id="color5" value="color5" onchange="updateTotal()">orange
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="color" id="color6" value="color6" onchange="updateTotal()">pink
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="color" id="color7" value="color7" onchange="updateTotal()">other
        <input type="text" name "color">
        <br>
        </fieldset>
```

And hide all others, except **Shipping**.

Here's how it seems if jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/simonapruse/Xdvem/

Can anyone help with suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
  function hideOthers(selectedValue) {
        var tipography = document.getElementById('tipography'),
            spiral = document.getElementById('spiral');
        if(selectedValue === 'book1') {
            spiral.style.display = 'none';
            tipography.style.display = 'block';
        } else if(selectedValue === 'book2') {
            spiral.style.display = 'block';
            tipography.style.display = 'none';
        }
  }
```

See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zS75r/1/)

Comment: This looks just great, but when I put it in my code, nothing happens. I seems that problem is that I put JS code in the wrong place. When I remove my function updateTotal(); then it works. Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/simonapruse/zS75r/2/

Comment: yes, you can also check my fiddle. I am calling the hideOthers() method inside the updateTotal().

Answer (score 0):

You can add onchange event on the first fieldset, and add ids to the fieldset you want to hide display

```
<fieldset onchange="RadioChanged()">
    <legend id="type">Book type:</legend>
    <input type="radio" name="books" id="book1" value="book1" onchange="updateTotal()">1.Tipography
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="books" id="book2" value="book2" onchange="updateTotal()">2.With spiral
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="books" id="book3" value="book3" onchange="updateTotal()">3.With unryu paper
    <br>
</fieldset>
<fieldset id='book1Field'>
    <legend id="tipcolor">1.Choose tipography book color:</legend>
    <input type="radio" name="color" id="color1" value="color1" onchange="updateTotal()">green
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="color" id="color2" value="color2" onchange="updateTotal()">orange
    <br>
</fieldset>
<fieldset id='book2Field'>
    <label id="color" class="hidden">2.Chooes spiral book color:</label>
    <input type="radio" name="color" id="color3" value="color3" onchange="updateTotal()">green
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="color" id="color4" value="color4" onchange="updateTotal()">blue
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="color" id="color5" value="color5" onchange="updateTotal()">orange
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="color" id="color6" value="color6" onchange="updateTotal()">pink
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="color" id="color7" value="color7" onchange="updateTotal()">other
    <input type="text" name "color">
    <br>
    </fieldset>
```

Then in javascript

```
function RadioChanged()
{
 if(document.getElementById('book1').checked)
 {
    document.getElementById('book2Field').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('book1Field').style.display='initial';
 }
 else if(document.getElementById('book2').checked)
 {
    document.getElementById('book1Field').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('book2Field').style.display='initial';
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- You need to write a javascript function like - OnBookType_Click.
- And associate it to the onClick event handler for the Book Type check boxes.
- Provide Id attribute to all your fieldset's.
- in JS function, check for the id or value of the checkbox selected, and accordingly the corresponding fieldset can be made visible by accessing it by ID. And make invisible all other fieldset s.